# typescript extended generic is not propagated why?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

Did come across a situation that puzzles me. Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
type TInputs<A> = A[] | Iterable<A> | Record<string, A>

type TTest = <A, Src extends TInputs<A>>(src: Src) => (x: A) => A

declare const arr: number[]
declare const t: TTest

t (arr) // infered as const t: <{}, number[]>(src: number[]) => (x: {}) => {}
// expected const t: <number, number[]>(src: number[]) => (x: number) => number
```

I do not understand why `A` is not *saved* ? any reason why it's *infered* as `{}`in this case?
And besides understanding how to pass that issue ?

Thanks in advance for any answer
Seb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler will not use a generic constraint as an inference position.  See [this similar GitHub question](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20963) for discussion about it.  That means that while `t(arr)` causes `Src` to be inferred as `number[]`, the resulting constraint `number[] extends A[]` cannot be used to infer `A`.  And since nothing else can be used to infer `A`, the inference fails with the "I give up" empty type `{}`.

To fix it... you probably don't actually need two type parameters.  If you want `A` to always be the element type of the `Src` array, then you can just get that element type by doing a [lookup](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) of `Src`'s `number`-index property type, that is: `Src[number]` in place of `A`:

```
type TTest = <Src extends any[]>(src: Src) => (x: Src[number]) => Src[number]

declare const arr: number[]
declare const t: TTest
t(arr)  // const t: <number[]>(src: number[]) => (x: number) => number
```

Looks like it works to me.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

---

UPDATE

Given your new types, one might use conditional type and `infer` to get `A` from `Src`, like this:

```
type AFromSrc<Src extends TInputs<any>> = Src extends TInputs<infer A> ? A : never;
type TTest = <Src extends TInputs<any>>(src: Src) => 
  (x: AFromSrc<Src>) => AFromSrc<Src>
```

This should also work as long as the compiler can infer `A` from `TInputs<A>`.  That depends on `TInputs<>` being transparent enough to the inference algorithm.  You should check to see if it works for you.  If not you might have to be more clever.

But if it *does* work then you might want to use the following, simpler signature:

```
type TTest = <A>(src: TInputs<A>) => (x: A) => A
```

That is, keep `A` and compute `Src` from it.  This involves no conditional types but does expect the compiler to be able to infer `A` from a value of type `TInputs<A>`.  If it can, great.  If not, you will need to use the first signature and a custom `AFromSrc` that helps the compiler determine `A`.

Okay, good luck again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick answer - one issue though is that the Src is not that simple :/ It's defined as so: `type TInputs<A> = TArrays<A>| Iterable<A> | Record<string, A>` with `type TArrays<A> = A extends number ? A[] | TTypedArray : A[]` -- not sure how to use the lookup in that case - I'll edit the question and thx a lot for the link btw ;)

Comment: Removed the issue by simply removing the `A`generic but then got an issue on the `TArray` type since i need to allow TypedArray only if type is a number, any thought ?

Comment: updated to look at new types in your question (although I have no idea what `TTypedArray` is so your mileage may vary)

Comment: yup just saw your update, didn't think to use infer (still quiet new héhé) - `TTypedArray` is simply a type regrouping all js typed arrays ;) -- but with your `AFromSrc` I should be just fine ^^ Thanks a lot

Comment: For you're second solution it will not work as I need the `Src` type for the *actual return type*